# What happens if two people try to buy a domain at the same time?

Tags: domains

If two people buy a particular domain at the same time from different providers, what will happen?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: The first registration attempt to be processed will get it.

Comment: Depending on the processing of the request, I guess the first provider who makes a formal request to register the domain at the main registrar for that tld, would win the race for his client?

Comment: I think the OP is talking about requests at the exact same time, however, in the computer world, there is no such thing.

Comment: Computer operate in microseconds, so there is no anything like same time, because human don't do things in microseconds, there is always some gape. Also I agree to pit, may be your domain registrar accept your request to register any domain, but ICANN check who made a first request. So in very minor case, it is also happen that domain registrar [allowed to register some domain](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/i-purchased-domain-googlecom-via-google-domains-sanmay-ved), but after few days they refuse to accept it, there are some many TOS/Policy can deny your request anytime.

Comment: Unless you had billions of users attempting to all register the same domain then possibly duplicate times could occur but you have more chance of winning the Euro Millions every week for a decade than this ever occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two requests are made through different registrars, whichever EPP request is processed by the registry first will succeed, and the second one will fail. How this failure is handled will depend on the registrar.

If the two requests are made through the same registrar, the results will depend on the registrar. In practice, the first request *should* "win", but some registrars may not have tested this case, and weird things may happen.

Comment: Had to approve this answer as I experienced this firsthand a few days ago. :D